Reledmac for Arabic critical edition: problems with Left-to-right apparatus and \Xgroupbyline
I am typesetting a critical edition with reledmac of an Arabic text. To typeset the Arabic, I use ArabXeTex.
I would like to have the entries in the apparatus grouped by line (\Xgroupbyline) and the apparatus running left-to-right. I have managed to obtain a LTR apparatus only by leaving each entry on one single line, but when I add the \Xgroupbyline options, the apparatus goes back to RTL. Below you find my working example. Maybe I should upload the bidi package with polyglossia, but I have conflicts with ArabXeTex I cannot fix.
I would by grateful for any help!
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=3cm, bottom=3cm,inner=2.5cm, outer=1.5cm, heightrounded}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage{greek}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.2]{Amiri}

\usepackage[series={A}, noend, nopenalties, nofamiliar]{reledmac}

\Xafterrule{8pt}
\Xparafootsep{$\parallel$}
\Xlemmaseparator{]}

\firstlinenum{1} \linenumincrement{1}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\Afootnoterule}{\left@footnoterule\par}
\makeatother
\Xnumberonlyfirstinline[A]
\Xgroupbyline[A]

\Xbhookgroup[A]{\LTR}
\Xafterlemmaseparator[A]{0.5em}
\Xbeforelemmaseparator[A]{0.25em}
\Xlinerangeseparator{\null-\null}
\Xbeforeinserting{\LTR}


\usepackage{arabxetex}
\newcommand{\ta}[1]{\textarab[novoc]{#1}}
\newcommand{\tanv}[1]{\textarab[voc]{#1}}
\newcommand{\myLR}[1]{\textLR{\textit{#1}}}

\newcommandx{\variant}[2][1,usedefault]{\Afootnote[#1]{#2}}
\newcommand{\co}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{arab}
    \beginnumbering
    
    \pstart
    fI \edtext{.siffaTi}{\variant{\myLR{om. G}}} al-^gu_dAm \edtext{\ta{wa"'sbAbihi \edtext{wa`alAmAtihi}{\variant{\myLR{om. B L}}}}}{\variant{\myLR{om. I}}}\pend
    
\pstart fa"'mmA \edtext{\ta{al-^gu_dAm fahwa \edtext{mar.duN}{\variant{\ta{`illaTu} \myLR{E H Se F}}}}}{\variant{\myLR{om. et add. in marg. L}}} \edtext{yu^gaffifu}{\variant{\ta{ya.hdu_t fI} \myLR{post corr. O1}}} sAi'r \edtext{a"'`.dA'}{\variant{\ta{al-a"'`.dA' a"'`.dA'} \myLR{Lo;} \ta{al-a"'`.dA'i} \myLR{ante corr. U;} \ta{al-a"'`.dA'i al-latI fI} \myLR{O}}} al-badni \edtext{\ta{wayufassiduhA bi-al-yabsi wahwa bimanzilaTi \edtext{sar.tAniN}{\variant{\ta{al} \myLR{ante add. B L}}} .hAdi_tiN fI ^gamI`i al-badni}}{\variant{\myLR{om. D}}} \edtext{\ta{wa.hudU_tuhu yakUnu}}{\variant{\ta{wayakUnu .hudU_tuhu} \myLR{E H}}} min .du`fi al-quwwaTi al-mu.gayyaraTi al-latI fI al-la.hmi \edtext{i"'_dA}{\variant{\ta{i"'_d} \myLR{E H I}}} kAna \edtext{_dalika}{\variant{\myLR{om. D}}}  min sU' mizA^gi bAridiN \edtext{yAbisiN}{\variant{\ta{wa} \myLR{ante add. A}}} wamin .galbaTi al-_hil.ti al-sawdAwI `alY al-dam \edtext{wa"'ifsAduhu}{\variant{\ta{a"'w fasAduhu} \myLR{H}}} a"'yyAhu faya.sIru i"'lY sAi'r al-a"'`.dA' \edtext{liyu.ga_d_dUhA}{\variant{\ta{liyu.ga_d_dUhu} \myLR{D}}} \edtext{\ta{fayu^gaffifuhA wayufassiduhA bi-al-yabs \edtext{wayufassidu}{\variant{\ta{fayufsidu} \myLR{U}}} ma`a _dalika \edtext{a"'_hlA.t}{\variant{\ta{liB}  \myLR{ante add. Par;} \ta{al-a"'_hlA.t al-llatI fI al-badni} \myLR{L;} \ta{al-'a_hlA.t} \myLR{O}}} \edtext{al-badni wayufassidu al-minY}{\variant{\ta{waal-minY} \myLR{O}}}}}{\variant{\myLR{om. D}}} \edtext{i"'_d}{\variant{\ta{i"'_dA} \myLR{Par1 D M U, ante corr. Par}}} \edtext{\ta{\edtext{kAnat}{\variant{\ta{ha_dihi} \myLR{post add. E H}}} al-a"'_hlA.tu waal-minY i"'nnamA \edtext{.hudU_tuhumA}{\variant{\ta{.hudU_tuhA} \myLR{U}}}}}{\variant{\ta{kAna .hudU_tuhumA} \myLR{O}}} \edtext{`an}{\variant{\ta{min} \myLR{Par O}}} al-dam .hattY a"'nna \edtext{\ta{ha_dihi al-`illaTu}}{\variant{\ta{ha_dA al-mar.du} \myLR{G}}}  \edtext{ta`adU}{\variant{\ta{tata`addY} \myLR{E;} \ta{tu.ga_d_dI} \myLR{U;} \ta{tu`dI} \myLR{O}}} \edtext{i"'lY}{\variant{\myLR{om. F}}} al-nasli fata.hdu_tu bi-al-a"'wlAdi \edtext{\ta{wa_dalika a"'nna}}{\variant{\ta{li"'anna} \myLR{G;} \ta{wa_dalika li"'anna} \myLR{E H Par1 Le Se F O}}}  ^gawhara al-minY mimman \edtext{ha_dihi}{\variant{\ta{al-`illaTi ya`dU i"'lY al-nasli} \myLR{post add. I}}}  .hAluhu yakUnu mu_htali.t"aN bi-al-a"'_hlA.ti al-radI'aTi al-mu.hdi_taTi \edtext{\ta{liha_dA al-mar.di}}{\variant{\ta{liha_dihi al-`illaTi} \myLR{E H G Se F U}}} \edtext{waal-walad}{\variant{\ta{faal-walad} \myLR{G}, \ta{al-mawlUdu} \myLR{A;}, \ta{waalmawlUd} \myLR{U;} \ta{fI al-walad} \co{D}}} al-mutakawwanu min \edtext{ha_dA}{\variant{\ta{ha_dihi} \myLR{F}}} al-minY takUnu a"'_hlA.tu badnihi \edtext{mu^sAkilaT"aN}{\variant{\ta{mu^sAkil"aN} \myLR{Se F}}} liha_dihi al-a"'_hlA.ti \edtext{wa"'`.dA'uhu}{\variant{\ta{waal-"'`.dA'u} \myLR{Se F}}} al-a"'.slyaTu mutakawwanuTi min ^gawhahirihA \edtext{faliha_dA}{\variant{\ta{fali_dalika} \myLR{F}}} \edtext{mA}{\variant{\myLR{om. E Se F}}} \edtext{tata`addY}{\variant{\tanv{tu`dI} \myLR{A G H Le Par1 O, ante corr. Par}}}  \edtext{\ta{\edtext{\ta{ha_dihi al-`illaTu}}{\variant{\myLR{om. G}}}  min al-a"'bA' i"'lY al-a"'wlAdi waqad \edtext{ya`dU}{\variant{\ta{ta`dU} \myLR{H;} \ta{yata`addY} \myLR{B D E I L M Par U;} \ta{tu`dI} \myLR{O}}}  \edtext{\ta{\edtext{\ta{ha_dA al-mar.du}}{\variant{\myLR{om. G}; \ta{ha_dihi al-`illaTi} \myLR{E H}}} \edtext{a"'y.d"aN}{\variant{\myLR{om. Par Par1 L U}}}}}{\variant{\ta{a"'y.daN ha_dihi al-`illaTu} \myLR{H}}}}}{\variant{\myLR{om. Se F}}} \edtext{i"'lY}{\variant{\myLR{om. O}}} man \edtext{yu^gAlisu}{\variant{mu^gAlisu} \myLR{O}} \edtext{a"'.s.hAbahi}{\variant{\myLR{om. Se F}}} wayua"'wI ma`ahum lammA \edtext{yata.hallalu}{\variant{\ta{yan.hallu} \myLR{O}}} min a"'bdAnihim min al-bu_hAr \edtext{al-radI'}{\variant{\ta{al-radI'aTi} \myLR{Par1}}} \edtext{\ta{wayastan^siquhu man \edtext{ya.h.duruhum}{\variant{mu^gAlisuhum} \myLR{O}}}}{\variant{\myLR{om. Se F}}}\pend
\endnumbering
\end{arab}

\end{document}

